# What flavor SQL does MySQL use?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've [searched Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mysql%20sql%20flavor), but can't find an answer to this: what flavor SQL does MySQL use, if any?

- [mssql](/questions/tagged/mssql) = [t-sql](/questions/tagged/t-sql)
- [sybase](/questions/tagged/sybase) = [t-sql](/questions/tagged/t-sql)
- [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) = [pl-sql](/questions/tagged/pl-sql)
- [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) = ?

Comment: mysql uses it's own dialect called mysql

Comment: The statement "Oracle = PL/SQL" is wrong. PL/SQL is **only** for stored procedures in Oracle. Everything else is "just" SQL.

Comment: How is that possible? Let's take the MINUS operator, that doesn't have to be used in stored procedures.  I can use that in ad-hoc query.  The problem I have with your statement is saying "just sql" implies it is platform independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL uses its own flavor called MySQL itself.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL Differences from Standard SQL

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/differences-from-ansi.html